# Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed when adding redis configuration to env.php

Tags: magento2, redis

I try to add the 'cache' values (for enabling redis) to env.php using exactly the same configuration as is on my staging server and working fine and I get the error 'Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed'

I checked the array syntax and it is fine. No trailing or missing ) closures. diff'ing the files between the staging and live and they show only a difference in the intent of a single line.

Comment: please check once theme table. is there any unused theme please delete that record

Comment: There was a theme I removed, but I also removed the entry in the theme table. Just double checked.

Comment: theme tables on both systems (staging which is working with redis and the one I'm trying to change) appear identical